# Google Sheets : formula, script or extension to get classification tags for images automatically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula, google-apps, google-vision

I have a Google Sheet with a list of image URLs.

First column : image URLs.
Second column : tags describing the image (for example: "landscape, mountain, field, sunset, lake" for a landscape image with a mountain, field, sunset, etc...)

I would like to fill automatically my column 2 with a formula like "ImageTags(ImageUrl)".

Are there any formula, extension or script (already available :) ) for that?

Thanks !

Comment: Hello @Regis_AG, what solution did you go for? I'd love to hear about it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use [Google Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) to label your images. You can test the API to decide whether it suits your needs or not [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate).

There are two tutorials using Google Apps Script to call the API that can help you develop the exact code that you need:

1. [Using a service account to authenticate, detect labels and send a GMail message](https://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/get-an-email-when-your-security-camera-sees-something-new-apps-script--cloud-vision)
2. [Using oAuth2 to authenticate and label images](https://ctrlq.org/code/20534-google-cloud-apps-script)

As an example, using the following image:

[image]

And calling the API with the following parameters:

- HTTP Request

`POST https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate`

- Body

```js
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vwKt.jpg"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "LABEL_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You obtain the following result (5 Nov 2019):

```js
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "labelAnnotations": [
        {
          "mid": "/m/09j06",
          "description": "Hot air balloon",
          "score": 0.9889263,
          "topicality": 0.9889263
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/01j51",
          "description": "Balloon",
          "score": 0.95322704,
          "topicality": 0.95322704
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/02p81ht",
          "description": "Hot air ballooning",
          "score": 0.9223063,
          "topicality": 0.9223063
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/0cmqr_4",
          "description": "Party supply",
          "score": 0.9016293,
          "topicality": 0.9016293
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/01d40f",
          "description": "Dress",
          "score": 0.86037284,
          "topicality": 0.86037284
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/07yv9",
          "description": "Vehicle",
          "score": 0.7725018,
          "topicality": 0.7725018
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/01bqvp",
          "description": "Sky",
          "score": 0.7326111,
          "topicality": 0.7326111
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/0ds99lh",
          "description": "Fun",
          "score": 0.7039424,
          "topicality": 0.7039424
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/016pp7",
          "description": "Happy",
          "score": 0.6789371,
          "topicality": 0.6789371
        },
        {
          "mid": "/m/06bm2",
          "description": "Recreation",
          "score": 0.6695586,
          "topicality": 0.6695586
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```